# Строка, числа и скобки

Tags: строки, c++

![alt text][1]На вход подается что-то типа: (12 32(32 12)).
Мне считать скобки перед числом, увидев число, выполнить: `res=a[i]*(0.5)^(b[i])`, где `a[i]` — это какое-то число из строки ввода, `b[i]` — скобочный итог к моменту, и соответсвенно суммировать такие результаты до конца строки.

Вот пример моей программы, но она возводит в степени не числа, а цифры (т.е. делит каждое число на цифры):

```
    using namespace std;
int main() {

    string str, st;

    int index = 0, k = 0, ind = 0, index1 = 0,s = 0;
    long double  res = 0;

    char chr;
    getline(cin, str);

    while (index < str.length())
    {
        chr = str[index];

        if ((chr == '1') || (chr == '2') || (chr == '3') || (chr == '4') || (chr == '5') || (chr == '6') || (chr == '7') || (chr == '8') || (chr == '9') ||(chr=='0') )
        {
            while ((str[index] == '1') || (str[index] == '2') || (str[index] == '3') || (str[index] == '4') || (str[index] == '5') || (str[index] == '6') || (str[index] == '7') || (str[index] == '8') || (str[index] == '9')|| (str[index] == '0'))
            {
                st[ind] = str[index];

                index1 = index;
                ind++;
                index++;

            }

            k = atoi(st.c_str()); cout<<"k="<<k<<" ";
            res = res + k*pow(0.5, s); cout<<"res"<<res<<endl;
            index = index1;

            ind = 0;

        }
        chr = str[index];
            if (chr == '(')
            {
                s = s + 1;

            }
            if (chr == ')')
            {
                s = s - 1;

            }

            st.clear();
std::cout << (st.empty() ? "YES" : "NO") << endl;
        index++;
    }

    cout << round(res * 100) / 100.;
    system("pause");
}
```

Пишет, что строка st, очищается, а на тестах иногда добовляет в конец цифры из предедущей строки.
Например (3332 554) выдает второе число как 5542, вместо 554.

Comment: Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С первой встретившейся цифры, до тех пор пока встречаются цифры, записывайте их в строку, когда встретите не цифру, вызываете atoi, получаете число, очищаете строку и т.д.

**UPDATE**

http://ideone.com/XdNwhF

P.S. Это очень простая задача и не справляться с таким это плохо, на вашем этапе советую порешать алгоритмические задачки самостоятельно, чтобы набраться опыта, например, тут [acmp.ru](http://acmp.ru/), сам когда-то таким был.

**Обновление**

Проблема в том, что нельзя в string в с++ добавлять символы с помощью оператора `[]`. То, что компилятор на это не ругается, это как раз один из способов выстрелить себе в ногу, как часто говорится.

```
st[ind] = str[index];
```

Вот в этой строке ошибка. Это ведет к такому поведению. Почему так происходит? Когда вы только создаёте переменную, её длина равна 0. Добавляя в неё символы с помощью оператора `[]`, предположу, что длина так и остаётся равна 0. Вы можете это проверить, добавив отладочный вывод до и после `st.clear()`.

Если делать так:

```
cout << "st:" << st << endl;
st.clear();
cout << "st_clear:" << st << endl;
```

то вам выведет

> st:
> st_clear:

То есть оба вывода выведут пустую строку, в то время как

```
cout << "st:" << st.c_str() << endl;
st.clear();
cout << "st_clear:" << st.c_str() << endl;
```

выведет на вашем примере

> st:3332
> st_clear:5542

По сути, в вашем случае `st.clear()` не очищает строку, поскольку её длина и так 0. При этом в память по этому адресу при использовании оператора `[]` пишутся цифры все равно. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил.

Comment: @iksuy, почему-то строка не всегда очищается, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @doomsday, обновил ответ

Comment: @iksuy,спасибо большое, я понимаю, что программа очень проста, и мой вариант тоже рработает, если очищать как вы: st = "", а если очещать st.clear() и числа отличаются ровно на один разряд, то в конец меньшего припысывалась цифра из предыдущего. Я не понимаю, откуда она берется. Ведь строка пуста. И если числа отличабтся больше, чем на один разряд, то все нормально работает.

Comment: @doomsday, проблема в том, что нельзя в string в с++ добавлять символы с помощью оператора []. то что компилятор на это не ругается, это как раз один из способов выстрелить себе в ногу, как часто говорится.

    st[ind] = str[index];

вот в этой строке ошибка. это ведет к такому поведению.
почему так происходит? когда вы только создаёте переменную, её длина равна 0. добавляя в неё символы с помощью оператора [] предположу, что длина так и остаётся равна 0. вы можете это проверить, добавив отладочный вывод до и после st.clear()

Answer (score 2):

[[@doomsday](/users/24309/doomsday)](/users/24309/doomsday): *"Я не понимаю, откуда она берется. Ведь строка пуста."*

Глядя на программу в вопросе, не очевидно, правильно ли она манипулирует индексы `index`, `index1`, `ind`, что может вызывать ошибку. Можно посмотреть в отладчике (таком как gdb) на значения индексов с вводом, который ведёт к ошибке, чтобы убедиться, что индексы имеют ожидаемые значения, или можно переписать эту программу, не используя индексы вообще:

```
#include <stdint.h> /* uintmax_t */ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT_FAILURE */

int main(void) {
  long double sum = 0.0; /* result */
  uintmax_t depth = 0, /* how deep parens are nested */
    number = 0; /* the current number */
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') 
      number = 10*number + (c - '0'); /* build number from digits */
    else { /* not a digit */
      /* result += a[i] * (0.5)**(b[i]) */
      sum += (long double)number / (1U << depth); /* number >> depth */
      number = 0; /* reset number */

      if (c == '(')
        ++depth; 
      else if (c == ')') {
        if (depth == 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        --depth;
      }
    }
  }
  if (printf("%Lf\n", sum) < 0)  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  return feof(stdin) ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Для краткости не приведены сообщения об ошибке и обработка ошибок переполнения, потери точности.

[Исполняемый пример](http://ideone.com/UZE8qo).